# Why does my textarea's border width change when I set my Firefox colors in the browser acessibility settings?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/rPpYE/1/), with the following HTML and CSS:

Html

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

CSS

```
/*Note: The default border is 3 without this rule.*/
input[type="text"] { border: 0px; }
```

In Firefox (I tested 3.6 & 7), if I inspect the textarea's box model I get zero borders, as expected.

However, if I go to `Edit->Preferences->Content->Colors` and uncheck the `"Allow pages to choose their own colors"` checkmark, the textarea's border changes back to 3, *apparently ignoring the explicit CSS settings!*!

- Has anyone come across a similar kind of issue when overriding colors like this?
- Is this to be somewhat expected or is it a FF bug?
- I didn't test / don't know how to test changing colors on other browsers, do they have the same issue?
- **Is it possible to work around the border changing?**

---

*Edit:*  Made the test case on JSFiddle more useble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the code that's supposed to drop native theming of form controls on style changes to them.  When that checkbox is unchecked, that code more or less stops working correctly for non-color properties.  And the OS default theme can specify whatever border width it deems necessary, of course.

I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700221 on this.